# Show data values in plotly icicle chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to show my value data within each box of my icicle chart, but the `udpate_traces` command I've used before for bar charts isn't working:

```
import plotly.express as px
# df is a pandas dataframe with columns level_1,2,3 and total
fig = px.icicle(df, path=['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3'], values='total')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate="%{values:.1}")
```

This just prints out the text inside the "" in the icicle chart rather than the 'total' values to one decimal place. (Writing `"%{total:.1}"` does the same thing too.

Is there a way to display the values below the category label in a plotly icicle chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`texttemplate`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/icicle/#icicle-texttemplate) requires `value` (without 's'):

```
fig.update_traces(texttemplate="%{value:.1}")
```